# New preview for MSAL login redirect for Xamarin droid fails

Tags: redirect, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2015 with the new MSAL preview v.1.1.0. The app calls the PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync which pulls up the login form in Chrome on the mobile device. The login is successful, but when it redirects I get the error message "This site can't be reached. The webpage at msal[my app id]://auth/?code=[auth code]... might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

When stepping through the app I see that the PublicClientApplication's redirect uri property is set to msal[my app id]://auth. And that is the same custom redirect uri that I entered into the Azure B2C tenant application.

Does anyone have any suggestions from that error of what I should check? Thanks.

Comment: OK. I figured it out. I missed the instruction in step 6b on the new sample app: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native. There needs to be a BrowserTabActivity added inside the application element of the AndroidManifest.xml file. See the link on github for specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the [*Integrate Azure AD B2C into a Xamarin forms app using MSAL* sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native).

This issue generally has the following causes:

- **You haven't configured your RedirectURI correctly in your [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.Droid/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml#L12)**, double check that you've populated both the scheme and the host correctly, where scheme only includes msal[APPLICATIONID] without colon, slashes or '*auth*' and the host while the host only includes '*auth*'
- **You haven't configured your RedirectURI correctly in your [MainActivity.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.Droid/MainActivity.cs#L23)**, double check that it matches the full redirect URI, meaning that it does include colon, slash and *'auth'* like so: msal[APPLICATIONID]://auth
- **You're missing the [OnActivityResult method that calls the AuthenticationContinuationHelper](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/blob/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.Droid/MainActivity.cs#L27-L31)**.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I figured it out. I missed the instruction in step 6b on the new sample app: [https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native‌​](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native). There needs to be a BrowserTabActivity added inside the application element of the AndroidManifest.xml file. See the link on github for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Chrome which is not installed on all images inside your emulator.

Running in an Android Emulator

MSAL in Android requires support for Custom Chrome Tabs for displaying authentication prompts. Not every emulator image comes with Chrome on board: please refer to this document for instructions on how to ensure that your emulator supports the features required by MSAL.