# MSAL Sign In with JIT Migration Fails on Android Only Using Xamarin Forms

Tags: redirect, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2015 with the new MSAL preview v.1.1.0. The app calls the PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync which pulls up the login form in Chrome on the mobile device.

This makes my question similar to this question: [New preview for MSAL login redirect for Xamarin droid fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208516/new-preview-for-msal-login-redirect-for-xamarin-droid-fails/45422306#45422306).

There are two differences. First I am intermittently getting a different error. See the highlighted difference: "This site can't be reached. The webpage at msal[my app id]://auth/?`state`=..."

Second, my signin is calling a WebApi, which migrates a user from a SQL database to Azure B2C Active Directory. I am following the example below for this part: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/Migration-JIT-sample.

I noticed that this usually happens when a user is migrated from my database to Azure B2C. In this case the signin is getting called twice. Once to migrate the user and then another time to sign the user in. The error also appeared to be happening intermittently when the user was not migrated, usually if I had not tried to sign in for a few hours, which may have been a different bug. Otherwise, the signin works fine. Also, this error does not occur on iOS. It is an Android only bug.

I think the intent listener on Android is not working correctly. When I get the ""This site can't be reached..." error, if I open the site in Chrome from my Android application, I am re-directed to my application and signed in. This makes me think the link is correct, but the listener is not working.

I am guessing this may be a bug in the line of code below, which is in the OnActivityResult method of the MainActivity.  AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: Let's try to break these problems into smaller pieces if possible.  Are you able to reproduce the MSAL AcquireTokenAsync problem if you are using a built-in "Sign-up or Sign-in" policy?  (I'm hoping we can break out your issues on the JIT migration into a separate question if they are unrelated)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a solution. I had been signing in as multiple users and the issue had been happening intermittently outside of the JIT migration, but consistently during the JIT migration. On other forums I noticed that people had user caching issues. So, right before signing in I made sure to remove all of the users from the cache.

```
foreach (var user in App.PCA.Users)
{
     App.PCA.Remove(user);
}
```

PCA is an instance of PublicClientApplication. I haven't seen any "This site can't be reached." issues since then.